# Remote powershell from windows 7 home premium

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell

Does anyone know if remote powershell (as a server not a client) will work on windows 7 home premium?

i found a post [here](http://community.idera.com/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/238/t/10826) saying home edition doesn't have the required networking bits but it doesn't go into any detail ideally i was wanting to see something from Microsoft saying what isn't supported with winrm included in the list.

i did also find [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/819559-how-to-enable-rdp-in-windows-7-home-premium) saying remote desktop isn't supported so maybe any remote authentication doesn't work?

I was also getting a access denied error shown below when running `winrm quickconfig` but fixed this using my own answer to this post so this could be unrelated to using home premium (i had already upgraded it to pro before finding the fix).

```
WSManFault
   Message = Access is denied.

Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005
Access is denied.
```

Comment: Does icm work for you?

Comment: @InterLinked what is icm? only thing i could find was Image Color Management which i'm guessing from the name is not relevant.

Comment: Invoke Command - I learned all about PowerShell through Microsoft's MVA program - as it's free, I suggest you take a look at their Intro Course, specifically the module on Remoting, which goes into the commands and processed used to use icm

Comment: @InterLinked looks pretty interesting and can't complain at that price :D i'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the 0x80070005 error was being caused by the account password being blank however as i had already upgraded the edition of windows to pro i'd still be interested if home premium can support winrm

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a little different, but I hope my answer will help someome.
I was able to configure PS Remoting for my Windows 7 Home Premium.

First of all you should check this doc: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6

I checked everything here and still had an error "Unable to check the status of the firewall" when trying to run `Enable-PSRemoting`

Then I found out my WinRM config have zero listeners. You can check this by running below command:

```
dir WSMan:\localhost\Listener
```

If you have empty response, you should manually add default listener:

```
New-WSManInstance winrm/config/Listener -SelectorSet @{Address="*";Transport="http"}
```

Answer (score -1):

To enable Powershell Remoting, we could enable WinRM and set the Firewall rules.
You could check the link below about enable Powershell Remoting via Group Policy.
https://www.briantist.com/how-to/powershell-remoting-group-policy/
For the error 0x80070005 means access deny, you could refer to the link below about winrm quickconfig Access denied error.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/b293be63-db96-4839-be3a-a071369e12af/winrm-quickconfig-access-denied-error?forum=virtualmachinemanager